# MySQL less than or greater than not working when getting specific records with limit

Tags: mysql

I have a table as shown below with 5 records. I wanted to get rest of all records with amount less than 2000. Except last/latest two records.

| invoiceId | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1156 | 2023-02-26 12:59 PM | 28500.00 |
| 1157 | 2023-02-26 01:01 PM | 300.00 |
| 1158 | 2023-02-26 01:02 PM | 850.00 |
| 1159 | 2023-02-26 01:02 PM | 29500.00 |
| 1160 | 2023-02-26 01:03 PM | 850.00 |

This is the result I wanted(leaving latest 2 and get rest of all records amount below 2000):

| invoiceId | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1157 | 2023-02-26 01:01 PM | 300.00 |
| 1158 | 2023-02-26 01:02 PM | 850.00 |

```sql
SELECT amount
from invoice
where invoiceDate LIKE '%2023-02-26%'
AND (amount < 2000)
ORDER BY invoiceId DESC
LIMIT 2,6
```

when I tried above query, it returns only one record 300 instead of expected 300 and 850. why?

But it works when tried with...

```sql
(amount > 0) or (amount > 300) or (amount > 500) -- as expected, 
(amount > 0), -- returns 300 and 850 and 28500.
(amount > 300), -- returns 850 and 28500.
(amount > 500), -- returns 850 and 28500.
```

But again it doesn't work when applied `(amount > 20000)`, it returns null instead of expected 20000. Why?

Comment: Please post your sample data as text, not image.

Comment: Limit 2, 6 will return 6 rows starting from the 3rd row.

Comment: 6 is just a large number to get the rest of records except latest 2. @SalmanA

Comment: Think about your `LIMIT` clause. Without it your query returns 3 rows. Starting the offset at the 3rd row (`OFFSET` is zero-based) returns only one row.

Comment: @hashi apparently you're trying to use limit to do what you should be doing with a where clause.

Comment: I got you, can a sub query solve this? @Phil

Comment: It's unclear which records you want to keep and which you want to omit

Comment: I knew the issue is in my limit which works after the where clause! Any idea to achieve this? to get the all records below 2000 except latest 2 records(leave latest as it is). @SalmanA

Comment: I have updated the question what I want. @Phil

Answer (score 1):

Decrement required number of excluding records from top id can solve this.

```
select * from invoice WHERE 
amount<2000 and invoiceId < (SELECT max(invoiceId)-1 FROM invoice)
```

But still expecting a smart answer apart this method.

Comment: This is as good an answer as any.  You should proably tick it.